# pf.conf in QNX Neutrino blocks every packet for my aliased IP

Tags: alias, packet, qnx-neutrino

I'm trying to apply packet filter for my QNX Neutrino system.In my situation, there are several aliased IP address to simulate other devices which yet to be developed.

What I'm struglling now is the setting of pf.conf.
Here is my `pf.conf` file.

```
block all
pass in on net1 proto tcp from any to any port 60000   # for simulated devices to master
pass out on net1 proto tcp from any to any port 50000  # for master to simulated devices
```

[image]

Whenever I apply the `pf.conf` above with `pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf`, I got communication error and the system never wakes up.

Even if I use the config below, I still got the same error.

```
block all
pass in on net1 all
pass out on net1 all
```

I don't understand why this happens...
Please give me an advise, thanks.